# glTexCoordPointer not working

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I'm trying to render a cube with textures using `glTexCoordPointer`, but the textures don't show up, but everything else is working fine (vertices and normals).

The fragment of code that enables textures is this:

```
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, material.texture()->id());
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, mesh.texcoords().data());

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, mesh.vertices().size());
```

I'm I missing something? Does this require shaders support?

Regards.

EDIT:

I managed to get textures working by calling `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` and `glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)`, but now I have another problem. The texture is blinking/flashing randomly when i move the camera around.

Comment: Can you post a bit more code? How are you setting up the texcoords() array? Do you enable GL_TEXTURES_2D? This doesn't require shaders support. Please, edit you question with further details.

Comment: I managed to get it working, but I have another problem. Check the question edit.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, actually i was loading the texture more than one time by distraction...